# Array object doesn't retain it's data

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an object that contains a array. On initialization of this object, the array is allocated and properly filled (as I can see in the debugger). This object is use to manage elements in a single view.

My problem is that when I try to call the object a second time, the array (and all other parameter of this object) are nil yet they have a memory address (again as seen in debugger).

This is the .h of the object in question :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "ObjectDef.h"
#import "AbstractNode.h"

@interface RenderingMachine : NSObject
{    
    NSMutableArray* _objectID;    // pair list
    NSMutableArray* _objectList;  // node list
    ObjectDef* _defs;             // definition of pairs

    unsigned int _size;
    unsigned int _edgeSize;

    AbstractNode* _lastNode;
}

-(void) InitializeMachine;
-(bool) AddObjectByIndex:(int)index :(float)x :(float)y :(float)originX :(float)originY;
-(bool) AddObjectByType:(NSString*)type;
-(NSMutableArray*) GetObjectID;
-(NSMutableArray*) GetObjectList;
-(unsigned int) Size;
-(void) DrawAllNode;
-(int) ComputePar;
-(void) ComputeLastEdge:(int)edgeCount;

//+(RenderingMachine*) GetMachine;

@end
```

My main problem right now is with _defs which is filled in InitDefinitions :

```
-(void) InitializeMachine
{
    _defs = [[ObjectDef alloc] init];
    [_defs InitDefinitions];
    _objectID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _objectList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _objectID = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[_defs GetPair:3]]; // adding the field node ID

    AbstractNode* rootNode = [[FieldNode alloc] init];
    _objectList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:rootNode]; // adding the field node as root node

    _size = 1;
    _edgeSize = 0;
}
```

What I'd like to know is if might be a bad alloc / init call or could it be a problem with the ARC of xcode because this particular file compiles with ARC (the other being ignore with "-fno-objc-arc").

Also, as mentionned the _defs is problematic, but all the property declared under @interface are having the same problem.

Comment: You need to include more code. ObjectDef's init method and InitDefinitions for starters, and whatever code you create RenderingMachine in and call InitializeMachine from. Also, please follow objective-c conventions with method, ivar and class naming - only classes start with upper case letters. It's amazing how much harder it makes it to read if you capitalise your method names!

Comment: Also you don't need to initialize mutable array twice, try with arrayWithCapacity and then addObject: or just arrayWithObject: alone. Then, as suggested, try to post more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you create a retained object with `_objectID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
and then you overwrite it with an autoreleased one `_objectID = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[_defs GetPair:3]];`

to add the object better use `[_objectID addObject:[_defs GetPair:3]];`

same thing with the _objectList Object